# Python: Getting TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object while calling a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, data-analysis

I have a text file which was converted to dataframe using below command:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Sriram\\Desktop\\New folder (4)\\aclImdb\\test\\result.txt", sep = '\t', 
             names=['reviews','polarity'])
```

Here the reviews column consists of all the movie reviews and polarity column consists of whether the review is positive or negative.

I have below feature function, to which my reviews column (nearly 1000 reviews) from dataframe needs to be passed.

```
def find_features(document):
words = word_tokenize(document)
features = {}
for w in word_features:
    features[w] = (w in words)
return features
```

I am creating a training dataset using below function.

```
trainsets = [find_features(df.reviews), df.polarity]
```

Hence by doing this, all the words in my reviews column will be split as a result of tokenize function in find_feature and will be assigned a polarity (positive or negative).

For example:

```
        reviews                           polarity
  This is a poor excuse for a movie        negative
```

For above case, after calling the find_features function, if the method inside the function is satisfied, I will be getting output as:

```
  poor    -  negative
  excuse  -  negative
```

and so on....

While I am trying to call this function, I am getting the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-76f9090c0532> in <module>()
 30     return features
 31 
---> 32 featuresets = [find_features(df.reviews), df.polarity]
 33 #featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for ((rev, category)) in   
 reviews]
 34 '''

 <ipython-input-79-76f9090c0532> in find_features(document)
 24 
 25 def find_features(document):
 ---> 26     words = word_tokenize(document)
 27     features = {}
 28     for w in word_features:

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in   
word_tokenize(text, language)
102     :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus
103     """
 --> 104     return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
105             for token in _treebank_word_tokenize(sent)]
106 

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in 
sent_tokenize(text, language)
 87     """
 88     tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
 ---> 89     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
 90 
 91 # Standard word tokenizer.

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in 
tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
1224         Given a text, returns a list of the sentences in that text.
1225         """
-> 1226         return list(self.sentences_from_text(text,  
realign_boundaries))
1227 
1228     def debug_decisions(self, text):

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in   
sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries)
1272         follows the period.
1273         """
-> 1274         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text,     
realign_boundaries)]
1275 
1276     def _slices_from_text(self, text):

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in 
span_tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
1263         if realign_boundaries:
1264             slices = self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
-> 1265         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
1266 
1267     def sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries=True):

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in  
<listcomp>(.0)
1263         if realign_boundaries:
1264             slices = self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
-> 1265         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
1266 
1267     def sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries=True):

C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in 
_realign_boundaries(self, text, slices)
1302         """
1303         realign = 0
-> 1304         for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
1305             sl1 = slice(sl1.start + realign, sl1.stop)
1306             if not sl2:

 C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in 
 _pair_iter(it)
 308     """
 309     it = iter(it)
 --> 310     prev = next(it)
 311     for el in it:
 312         yield (prev, el)

 C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in    
_slices_from_text(self, text)
1276     def _slices_from_text(self, text):
1277         last_break = 0
-> 1278         for match in   
self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
1279             context = match.group() + match.group('after_tok')
1280             if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How to call a function directly from a dataframe which has multiple rows of values (In my case reviews)?

Comment: could you provide the whole traceback message? I am unclear on which line is actually raising the error

Comment: I have updated the question with complete traceback message

Comment: Is it possible that there are missing values in the reviews column?

Comment: There are no missing values in review column.

Comment: 1. is `df.reviews` & `df.polarity` referring to the whole columns from the source dataframe?

2. are you passing the entire Series `df.reviews` to `find_features(df.reviews)` ?

3. how can you add the whole `dict` object returned by `find_features(df.reviews)` function call into a `list` at line `[find_features(df.reviews), df.polarity]`

Comment: @SriramChandramouli are you trying to associate all key-words returned by `find_features` for one single row-value of `reviews` column to the `polarity` column value of the same-row?

Comment: @JoshuaBaboo yes, they both refer to the whole columns from the source dataframe. I want to loop through all the values of review columns to find_features function. It will return set of values and those value should be linked to corresponding polarity column and its should be obtained in the list..... And, yes, I am trying to associate all key-words returned by find_features for one single row-value of reviews column to the polarity column value of the same-row. It repeats for all the values present in movie reviews column. (has more than 1000 reviews)

Comment: @SriramChandramouli try out the row-wise apply snippet I've added in the answer & see if it works

Answer (score 0):

going by your expected output mentioned:

  `poor    -  negative
  excuse  -  negative`

I will suggest: 

`trainsets = df.apply(lambda row: ([(kw, row.polarity) for kw in find_features(row.reviews)]), axis=1)`

adding a sample snippet for ref:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

print 'pandas-version: ', pd.__version__
data_str = """
col1,col2
'leoperd lion tiger','non-veg'
'buffalo antelope elephant','veg'
'dog cat crow','all'
"""
data_str = StringIO(data_str)
# a dataframe with 2 columns
df = pd.read_csv(data_str)

# a dummy function taking a col1 value from each row
# and splits it into multiple values & returns a list
def my_fn(row_val):
    return row_val.split(' ')

# calling row-wise apply vetor operation on dataframe
train_set = df.apply(lambda row: ([(kw, row.col2) for kw in my_fn(row.col1)]), axis=1)
print train_set
```

#### output:

```
pandas-version:  0.15.2
0    [('leoperd, 'non-veg'), (lion, 'non-veg'), (ti...
1    [('buffalo, 'veg'), (antelope, 'veg'), (elepha...
2        [('dog, 'all'), (cat, 'all'), (crow', 'all')]
dtype: object
```

@SriramChandramouli, hope I understood your requirement correctly.